# For security reasons framing is not allowed

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Whenever I access superuser.com it says **for security reasons, framing is not allowed ; Click Ok to remove the frames**.

How can i get rid off this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of that message? Is your ISP messing with your access?

Comment: either I can't see your screenshot or your screenshot is a big white image

Comment: @Sathya i have uploaded again.

Comment: If you have Greasemonkey installed, try disabling it.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133138/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-o

Comment: What browser is that?

Comment: It is Firefox...

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I have tried both firefox and chrome. it happens in both.

Comment: Do you have access to an iPad/Tablet/Phone/Other computer? Try that, it will simply tell us whether the problem is with your ISP or computer

Comment: Stack Exchange sites can't be accessed within frames. Perhaps the ISP is adding frames and making it look like there are none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in Comments you guys were right. The problem is no more and this was due to my ISP. As soon as I returned home the problem was gone.

This was not a problem of browser or system.

Comment: I am curious, though. Is your ISP adding frames to *every* site you visit? That doesn't look like a normal behavior...

Comment: @ValmikyArquissandas I don't know what was happening but when I think somehow it was related with ISP.